# Securimage empty session with ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, captcha

When submitting my form without ajax, the captcha validation with Securimage works, but when I want to submit with ajax, the captcha-code is always invalid. Do I have to add something specific in the ajax-call or change something in securimage.php?

```
$("#contact-form").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "contact.do.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#contactResponse").html(data);
                }
        });
});
```

Comment: It's possible the PHP session cookie doesn't get sent with the Ajax request.  Are you still unable to get it to work?

Comment: No, still not able to get it to work..

Comment: Feel free to contact me directly at phpcaptcha.org/contact if you would like some help getting it to work.  Also, included with the download is a file called example_form.ajax.php which should be in your securimage folder.  Try that file on your site and see if it works.  It uses jQuery to do an Ajax request to validate the captcha.  If it doesn't work it may be a PHP/session issue, if it does you might be able to use it as an example for your code.  But either way let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score -1):

use google ReCAPTCHA

example :

```
http://www.9lessons.info/2014/12/google-new-recaptcha-using-php-are-you.html
```

Ref :

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo
```

generate key here

```
  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list
```